# ModelAdminGroup add completely custom view

Tags: wagtail

I updated to the latest Wagtail and found ModelAdmin very useful. I rewrote to it most of my custom admin extends what cleaned up my code and also improved the maintainability. 
But I have still some admin views which are completely custom. I want them into explorer menu which was created for my ModelAdminGroup to have my custom tasks and ModelAdmin items grouped under one menu item. Is there any possibility how to achieve that?

Comment: Could you expand your question a bit more - maybe with some example code of the custom views and/or what you want your final menu structure to look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to be 100% sure based on your question, but it sounds like what you're looking to achieve could be done by overriding the [`get_submenu_items`](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/contrib/modeladmin/options.py#L546) method on your custom `ModelAdminGroup` class to append custom [`MenuItem`](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/admin/menu.py#L11) instances to the list before returning.

You might also find it useful to override [`get_admin_urls_for_registration`](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/contrib/modeladmin/options.py#L565) method to register new urls for your custom admin-related views.

Comment: How easy... Thanks! :)